# Send logs from specific pod to external server

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

We need to send large (very) amount of logs to `Splunk` server from only **one k8s pod**( pod with huge traffic load), I look at the docs and found this:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent

However, there is a **Note in the docs, that is stating about a significant resource consumption**. Is there any other option to do it? I mean more efficient ? As these pods handle traffic and we cannot add the additional load, that can risk it stability...

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Azure and AWS?

Comment: please refer below link, Splunk's best practice recommendations. 

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.0/Capacity/Referencehardware#Reference_host_specifications_for_distributed_deployments

Comment: @MrOverflow, can you please point me to the relevant link, as the link have general data which im not sure its related...

Comment: sure, i am not expert on Slunk. more familiar with other cloud provider for logging. but if you use any hook to get the stream data definitely it will consume some of your server's resource.  IMHO, run it on lower environment and evaluate the resource consumption and then go for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an official solution to get Kubernets logs: Splunk Connect for Kubernetes. Under the hood it also uses fluentd for the logging part.

https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes

You will find a sample config and a methodology to test it on microK8s first to get acquainted with the config and deployment: https://mattymo.io/deploying-splunk-connect-for-kubernetes-on-microk8s-with-helm/

And if you only want logs from a specific container you can use this section of the values file to select only logs from the container you're interested in:

```
  fluentd:
    # path of logfiles, default /var/log/containers/*.log
    path: /var/log/containers/*.log
    # paths of logfiles to exclude. object type is array as per fluentd specification:
    # https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#exclude_path
    exclude_path:
    #  - /var/log/containers/kube-svc-redirect*.log
    #  - /var/log/containers/tiller*.log
    #  - /var/log/containers/*_kube-system_*.log (to exclude `kube-system` namespace)
```

Comment: Thanks! to verify that I understand, it will look for all the pods logs in the cluster, and I need explicitly to remove the pods that I dont want to send the logs? in case we have many pods, its not a bit cumbersome ? there is no way from the beging to tell to it watch only pod with name `foo` ?

Comment: And also it works with DaemonSet, can we configure it to works like a Deployment?

Comment: The solution is designed for monitoring of all the container logs. To monitor logs from one container, specify it's path and nothing else in the fluentd section mentioned above `path: /var/log/containers/alberto-container*.log`

I guess it needs to run as a Daemonset as in a multinode cluster your pod can be spawn on whatever node.

Comment: If you have a hard requirement for not using Daemonsets you can experiment with these solutions. They should provide a starting point. One is based on fluentd and the other on splunkuniversalforwarder:  https://medium.com/@deepak4babu/splunk-monitor-a-log-path-present-inside-a-container-hosted-in-kubernetes-cluster-b3583d22212c  https://computingforgeeks.com/send-logs-to-splunk-using-splunk-forwarder/

Comment: Thank you, one question, if I use `path: /var/log/containers/alberto-container*.log` is it A good solution for my case "send to splunk only one pod logs" ? or this is abuse? what you would do for production for high load entries data e.g. 4000 records for second on pick which need to be send to splunk only from one pod ?

Comment: The solution should scale well enough for your use case because the receiving side (indexers or heavy forwarders having HEC enabled) can also be scaled horizontally if you notice they can no longer cope with incoming events.